# In spaCy is there a way to extract the sentence the entity has been extracted from?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

considering the following sentence:

> "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

and if I want to extract brown, extracting only brown is fairly easy to do however I want the following output:

> "brown" , "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this in Spacy.  You have to iterate over the entity *Span* objects and extract the sentence from each *Span* object. Here is an example:

```
    doc = nlp("John and Claire live in London. They have a dog. Claire walks her 
    dog everyday.")
    for entity in doc.ents:
       print('Entity extracted : ', entity.text)
       print('Sentence extracted from : ', entity.sent)
```

This should give you the following output :

```
Entity extracted :  John
Sentence extracted from :  John and Claire live in London.

Entity extracted :  Claire
Sentence extracted from :  John and Claire live in London.

Entity extracted :  London
Sentence extracted from :  John and Claire live in London.

Entity extracted :  Claire
Sentence extracted from :  Claire walks her dog everyday.

Entity extracted :  everyday
Sentence extracted from :  Claire walks her dog everyday.
```